# Can't get variables to work in Wordpress for Intercom Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, intercom

Intercom provide the following snippet to be injected before the body tag:

```
<script>
  window.intercomSettings = {
    app_id: "",
    name: "<?php echo json_encode($current_user->name) ?>", // Full name
    email: "<?php echo json_encode($current_user->email) ?>", // Email address
    created_at: "<?php echo strtotime($current_user->created_at) ?>" // Signup date as a Unix timestamp
  };
</script>
```

However, it creates the launcher with an error; stating to check the email variable. What should the variable be for Wordpress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not meant to be injected before body, it has to be before the body close tag .

```
<script>
  window.intercomSettings = {
    app_id: "",
    name: "<?=wp_get_current_user()->user_login?>", // Full name
    email: "<?=wp_get_current_user()->user_email?>", // Email address
    created_at: "<?=strtotime(wp_get_current_user()->created_at)?>" // Signup date as a Unix timestamp
  };
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, that's what I meant. I placed the snippet before the body close tag and got the error.

Comment: i've revised my answer, try that out.

Comment: Not sure how familiar you are with Intercom, they provide a snippet for logged-in users and one for visitors. Do you know if it's possible to put both snippets on the same page? ie when a user is logged out it uses the visitor script?

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to point out with the code example above that Intercom provides for PHP is that the `json_encode` is meant for array values and not single values. I had the same issue using that example when I realized that the email I was passing was looking like this after being rendered which caused it to break.

```
""user@example.com""
```

If you are just using a single value don't use `json_encode`. Just pass it as is.